# regularity of the matrix exponential

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

For every matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m^2}$ let
$$e^{A}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{A^{k}}{k!}$$ 
prove that the application $exp: A \rightarrow e^A$ is $C^{\infty}$
class.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: How are defining the derivative of "exp".  The function $e^{At} = \sum_{k+0}^ \infty A^tk/k!$ is certainly $C ^ \infty$ as a function of t, but that does not seem to be the same as the transformation  $A \rightarrow e^A$.

Comment: Any analytic function is $C^{\infty}$ and the coefficients of $e^{A}$ are analytic functions of the coefficients of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula that defines $e^A$ is a power series that converges on the entire space. Such a series can be differentiated termwise as many times as we want. Indeed, on any bounded subset the terms decay exponentially (uniformly in $A$), and taking derivatives does not change that: derivatives contribute only a polynomial factor. The uniform convergence of the series of derivatives implies that the sum is smooth.

Shorter version of the above: *real-analytic* $\implies$ $C^\infty$, which works in several variables just as well as in one.